# SQL Query needs to be optimized

Tags: sql

```
Table1
column1 || column1Name
=======================
udf1    || Name1
udf2    || Name2


Table2
column1 || udf1   || udf2
================
key1    || value1 || value2
```

Requirement is to write the query to find the key1 on the basis of Name1 passed with value1.
I am able to write it using dynamic sql but its performance is too low in case of large record set. Please suggest the optimistic way to write the sql query.

Comment: What query are we supposed to be optimizing?  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It is not about query optimization... it is about what is the optimal way to write queries for normalized tables... database is sql server 2008

Comment: Are you restricted to writing it as dynamic SQL?

Comment: no... it all about chosing the most optimal solution which gives better performance in case of large amount of data.

Comment: At least give an example with expected output given a particular input.

Comment: Input - Name1(table1),value1(table2), Output - Key1(table2)

Answer (score 0):

Although a poor example to start,  you'll get there in time as you post more questions.   Having a little more realistic data (good start) and showing expectations output also good thing instead of comment-based.

Anyhow, I don't know how many "udf" (inferring are user-defined-fields) and I would have an index on each column on its own.  I am running the query starting with Table1 (alias t1) and joining to table2 multiple times based on each respective "udf" column based on the value from table1... IN ADDITION, each left-join is also applying the 'value1' as that is what you are looking for.  It's possible that the 'value1' could exist in any of the possible table2 aliased joins.

The WHERE clause is specific to the 'name' you are looking for, and the following  AND NOT ( is null / is null ) for the UDF1 & 2 tables means I only want a record returned if either one of the alias instances DOES have a match... if none, ignore the record.

Finally, by the field selection of COALESCE(), I know that ONE of the two viaUDF aliases will have a match, so grab the Column1 first viaUDF1... if that is null, grab Column1 from viaUDF2

```
SELECT
      coalesce( viaUDF1.Column1, viaUDF2.Column1 ) as ReturnedKey
   from
      Table1 T1
      left join Table2 viaUDF1
         ON T1.Column1 = viaUDF1.udf1
         AND viaUDF1.udf1 = 'value1'
      left join Table2 viaUDF2
         ON T1.Column1 = viaUDF2.udf2
         AND viaUDF2.udf2 = 'value1'
   where
          T1.Column1Name = 'Name1'
      AND NOT (    viaUDF1.udf1 IS NULL 
                OR viaUDF2.udf2 IS NULL )
```

Now if you have 10+ UDF columns,  then all bets are off for performance, you'll have to left-join to every instance in a similar fashion because you can't inline join to a table based on a query (that I've ever seen) without doing it via Dynamic-SQL.